# ActionEvent stopped working with no obvious reason?

Tags: java, swing, actionevent

Recently I have been playing around with Java Swing and am trying to create a custom Minecraft server launcher. When I press the button labeled "properties", it is supposed to change to a new panel and did at one point. However, for some reason I am unable to see it no longer works. Can anyone please help?

```
package custommcserver;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener , ItemListener
{
    JPanel mainPnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    JPanel propPnl = new JPanel();
    JButton startBtn = new JButton("Start");
    JButton stopBtn = new JButton("Stop");
    JButton propBtn = new JButton("Properties");

    JCheckBox allowNether = new JCheckBox("Allow players to visit the Nether dimension");

    public Window()
    {
        super("Custom Minecraft Server Launcher") ;
        setSize(500,200) ; 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
        add(mainPnl) ;
        mainPnl.add(startBtn);
        mainPnl.add(stopBtn);
        mainPnl.add(propBtn);
        stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
        startBtn.addActionListener(this);
        stopBtn.addActionListener(this);
        propBtn.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {

        if (event.getSource() == stopBtn)
        {
            stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            startBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        if (event.getSource() == startBtn)
        {
            stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
            startBtn.setEnabled(false);


        if (event.getSource() == propBtn)
        {
            add(propPnl);
            mainPnl.setVisible(false);
            propPnl.setVisible(true);
            propPnl.add(allowNether);
        }

    }
}

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 issues:

1. The line

   `if (event.getSource() == propBtn) {`

   is within the `if` statement check for `startBtn` so there is effectively no check for this button. Move this out of that `if` statement block.
2. Call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the the `JFrame`

---

Side notes:

- `CardLayout` provides the functionality of replacing a component with another. Read [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- Use anonymous `ActionListener` class instances to avoid issue #1.

Comment: Thank-you. Tested it out and it works fine. Yet another lesson learnt in the world of Java for me.

Comment: I think thats enough for JFrame